# how can i get time from time picker

Tags: java, android, xml

I tried the usual way which is declaring in xml file.

```
    <TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/ChoosenTime"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

then I tried getting an instance by

```
TimePicker time = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.ChoosenTime);
```

but then the app crashes if I try to get the instance. here is the log.

07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{hasebou.karim.simplify/hasebou.karim.simplify.Volume}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1882)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at hasebou.karim.simplify.Volume.(Volume.java:26)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1068)
07-05 22:10:25.510: E/AndroidRuntime(27751):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)

Comment: What Exception are you getting? Post your Stack trace, please.

Comment: Where in your activity does the `findViewById()` call appear?

Comment: sorry my bad. I declared it outside of the oncreate; with other variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I declared it outside of the oncreate; with other variables

While you are welcome to *declare* your `TimePicker` there, `findViewById()` will not work until after `setContentView()` is called (or you otherwise cause the `TimePicker` to be created).